# Getting voltage on both travellers on a 3-way switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I recently moved into my current home. I tried to replace a lot of the switches to smart switches, and most of them worked except one. After switching that one (one of the two 3 way switches) to a smart switch I'm having these issues:

The smart switch always thinks that the light is on, but it can turn off/on just fine, well except that when it's off, it's still leaking some current and the bulb is still showing some light although very dim.
Here are my wiring situations:

Switch box 1 (where the smart switch goes to):

- two white wires shorted together before, I assumed these are neutral so connected to the neutral terminal of the smart switch.
- one black and one red wires connected as travellers before, so I connected them as travellers to the smart switch.
- one black wire as common, so I connected it to the line/load of the smart switch. The voltmeter reads 120V AC between this and the white wire so this should be the line.
- bare copper wire as ground, so I connected it to the ground of the smart switch

Switch box 2 (untouched):

- one black and one red wires connected as travellers before, so I connected them as travellers to the smart switch
- one white wire as common, so I connected it to the line/load of the smart switch
- bare copper wire as ground, so I connected it to the ground of the smart switch

The weird part is that when I measure the two travellers in box 2 with the ground as reference, one reads 120V AC but the other one reads 90V. This explains why the light is still showing some light even when off. Could this be coupling?

Comment: Model # of switch?

Comment: Yes, can you get us the make and model of the switch in question, as well as photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

A smart switch needs to get power, as opposed to a dumb switch which only needs to pass power along to lights when "on". Since the switch has *hot*, all it needs is *neutral* to get power from the regular AC source. Or it can get power from elsewhere:

- Battery - The problem is a battery might last 6 months or 1 year or maybe a bit longer, but eventually it will need to be replaced. The cost is minimal, but people often forget about batteries, or the switch will stop working when you least expect it, or it will fail in strange ways if the battery is low but not quite dead. So batteries are generally not the preferred solution.
- Neutral - In fact, recent changes to the National Electric Code *require* neutral in most switch boxes, which solves this problem. But older switch boxes often do not have neutral, and adding a neutral wire is very much a non-trivial task if the wires are in cables and the cables are inside finished walls.
- Ground - This is permitted under very limited circumstances, as neutral and ground are connected (bonded) in the main panel. There are limits to the amount of current that can be used this way and it can lead to problems if the lights are on a GFCI-protected circuit.
- Leak through Switched Hot - This is the old way of doing things. It works very well with incandescent bulbs. Unfortunately, with LEDs it does *not* work very well. Depending on the LEDs, it can cause a dim glow, flashing lights and/or premature failure of the LEDs.

So there is no perfect, one size fits all, solution. Based on symptoms, it sounds like you have "leak through switched hot". However, based on:

> two white wires shorted together before, I assumed these are neutral so connected to the neutral terminal of the smart switch.

it sounds like you have a smart switch that includes a neutral connection, which should *not* need to leak through switched hot.

More details on wiring and switch (e.g., does it *require neutral*, does it specify "LED compatible*) may help.